# Flutter: RenderBox was not laid out

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and I'm trying to populate a dropdown box with data from firestore using the document's name. I'm not sure how to do it so I searched for a reference. My reference had deprecated code which I edited so that might also be part of the problem. The code runs on chrome webview but doesn't on android. Help is greatly appreciated. I looked for other answers on the topic such as applying shrinkwrap however that didn't work.

**ERROR**

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a43b4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

**Code**

```
      body: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("currency")
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          const Text("Loading.....");
                        } else {
                          List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
                          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data!.docs.length; i++) {
                            DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                            currencyItems.add(
                              DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: snap.id,
                                child: Text(
                                  snap.id,
                                  style:
                                      const TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          return Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(width: 50.0),
                              DropdownButton(
                                items: currencyItems,
                                onChanged: (currencyValue) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedCurrency = currencyValue;
                                  });
                                },
                                value: selectedCurrency,
                                isExpanded: false,
                                hint: const Text(
                                  "Choose Currency Type",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                        return (const HomeView2());
                      }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```